# Не работает inline (telebot) кнопка в Callbackquery

Tags: python, telebot, callback, inline

Не работает кнопка при выборе боевик (должны появиться inline кнопки "Популярные" и "Новинки", но не появляются)

```
`@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
 def callback_query_one(call):
     keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
     if call.data == "cl_1":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Да")
        callback3_button =types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Боевик",callback_data="cl_3")
        keyboard.add(callback3_button)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Выберите жанр", reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call, callback_query_two)

     elif call.data == "cl_2":
         bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Нет") 
         bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Очень жаль!") 


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_query_two(call):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()   
    if call.data == "cl_3":
        bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, "Боевик") 
        callback18_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Популярные", callback_data = "cl_18")
        callback19_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Новинки", callback_data = "cl_19")
        keyboard.add(callback18_button, callback19_button)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Выберите", reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.chat.id, callback_query_three)'
```

Comment: фyнкции callback_query_one и callback_query_two объединить под одной функцию

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!